# Find a matching value in two workbooks, then make a mark if a condition is met

Tags: excel, vba

I'm not sure if this is possible but this is what I want to do:
I have two different workbooks.

Each row in Workbook A contains a value in column C. 
1. Find the value in column C of  workbook B (which is not just the row number), 
2. Move across to column G in the same row. 
If the value in column G is a zero, go back to Workbook A and input 0 in column H. 
If the value is anything other than a zero, input 1 in column H of Workbook A.
3. Continue until there are no more valid rows to 
search in workbook A (variable number).

I have about 200 worksheets to match up (same worksheet name, different workbooks), so I want to make sure that the VBA knows to go to the correct sheet. I'm happy to manually change the code by myself for each worksheet. Is that just done by Go to #### in workbook A and #### in workbook B?

I have basically zero knowledge of VBA, so I'm not sure even sure where to start. I think it would be a bunch of If statements?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several weapons you need:

1. `Range.Find(key)` returns a range object which matches the key.
2. `Range.Offset(r, c)` returns the range which is `r` rows down and `c` columns right.
3. Since the data in WorkbookA is variable, you can use `Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)` to obtain the last row of your data.
4. Loop through the worksheets in a workbook can be achieved by codes below

   ```
   Dim ws As Worksheets
   For Each ws In ThisWorkbook
       'do something
   Next ws
   ```
5. You can get the worksheet name by `ws.Name` and call a worksheet with the name by `Workbook.Worksheets(name)`

So here comes a code, you need to adjust by yourself.

```
Private Sub test()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Assuming the code is in workbook A, and we open workbook B here
    Dim wbA As Workbook, wbB As Workbook
    Set wbA = ThisWorkbook
    'May get a failure when the path is incorrect
    Set wbB = Workbooks.Open("FULL PATH OF WORKBOOK B")

    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    'Loop throuth wbA.Worksheets so we can get the job done in each worksheet
    For Each ws In wbA.Worksheets

        'Getting the last row in column C
        lastRow = ws.Range("C" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        'ws.Name to get the name, and find it in workbook B
        'May get a failure if there is no worksheet named after that
        With wbB.Worksheets(ws.Name)

            'Loop from C2 to the last data in C, assuming C1 is a title
            For i = 2 To lastRow

                'Range.Find returns a range with the key, and offset from C to G, which is 4 columns right.
                'May get a failure due to mismatching
                If .Range("C:C").Find(ws.Range("C" & i).Value).Offset(0, 4) = 0 Then
                    ws.Range("H" & i).Value = 0
                Else
                    ws.Range("H" & i).Value = 1
                End If
            Next i
        End With
    Next ws

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you newacc2240! It seems to be working so far, all I've had to do was change i to 14 and offset the column by 5.